# How to strip all visual composer shortcode/tags from wordpress's post_content fetched with custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, strip-tags, visual-composer

I am working on a web-service(API) where i am fetching result WP_query() function and parse that in JSON format. which will further use in android application.
The problem is the post_content i am getting with query is composed by visual composer and the whole content is in form of such tags like

```
[VC_ROW][/VC_ROW][VC_COLUMN]some text[/VC_COLUMN] etc.
```

I want to remove/strip all these shortcode from the content and retrieve only plain text from it. Is there any visual composer function through which i can achieve this thing

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-load.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/functions.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/shortcodes.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$post_name = $_REQUEST['page'];

if($post_name!=''){
    if($post_name=='services') {

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $page['services']['id'],
        'post_type'   => 'page', 
        'post_status' => 'published' 
    ); 
    $posts = get_children($args);
    foreach($posts as $po){
        $services_array[] = array('id'=>$po->ID,'title'=>$po->post_title,'image'=>get_post_meta($po->ID, 'webservice_page_image',true),'description'=>preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $po->post_content));
    }

    $post = array(
        'status'=>'ok', 
        'services'=>$services_array
    );
    echo json_encode($post);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you can try `strip_shortcodes()` and this function provided by wordpress.

Comment: @Rocky strip_shortcodes() Not worked, already tried before

Comment: Have you tried ? regex `preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $the_content);`

Comment: @Rocky yeah man it works. But why its not working with strip_shortcodes() It also having the same thing in that function

Comment: Can you share your code so, i can check why its not working from your side ?

Comment: It do not remove every shortcode. such shortcodes [vc_column_inner width=\"1\/3\"] are still left

Comment: shortcode added please check now

Comment: @Rocky source code added please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can try and easily add some short codes in array that you needs and also you can remove all shortcodes via below code.

```
$the_content = '[VC_ROW][VC_COLUMN]some text1[/VC_COLUMN] etc.[/VC_ROW][VC_COLUMN_INNTER width="1/3"][/VC_COLUMN_INNTER]';

$shortcode_tags = array('VC_COLUMN_INNTER');
$values = array_values( $shortcode_tags );
$exclude_codes  = implode( '|', $values );

// strip all shortcodes but keep content
// $the_content = preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $the_content);

// strip all shortcodes except $exclude_codes and keep all content
$the_content = preg_replace( "~(?:\[/?)(?!(?:$exclude_codes))[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $the_content );
echo $the_content;
```

you want to remain some shortcodes you can't use `strip_shortcodes()` for that.

Comment: for me now this code works
str_replace('[vc_column_inner width="1/3"]','',preg_replace("~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s", '', $po->post_content))

there are actually different parameters in vc_column, so if they comes i will remove them with str_replace. your answer make a little help. i will upvote it but its not the accurate solution

Comment: Look I have updated code also parameter not matters in shortcode, this regex only checks shortcode that you have used in array. you can run this code still `VC_COLUMN_INNTER` passed in array then and then it accepted in content with parameters.

Comment: I developed a free WordPress plugin to solve this problem, the plugin named ( Shortcode Cleaner Lite )
https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-cleaner-lite/
It provides an easy way to clean up unused, broken shortcodes from WordPress content automatically, so you can switch between themes and plugins without worrying and keep your content cleanly and fresh all the time, it is dealing with any theme (Divi, Avada…etc) shortcodes that are left when changing themes or plugins or page builders (Visual Composer, Elementor, Beaver…etc).

Comment: sorry, but neither the first nor the second preg_replace line removed the shortcodes from my content string.

Answer (score 5):

`I want to remove/strip all these shortcode from the content and retrieve only plain text from it.`

Solution that worked for me:

```
$content = strip_tags( do_shortcode( $post->post_content ) );
```

`do_shortcode` triggers all visual composer shortcodes and thus returns html+text;

`strip_tags` removes all html tags and returns plain text.

Comment: after some research this was the smartest way of dealing with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution, solved.
Just add the following code to file **wp-includes/rest-api.php**, at the bottom:

```
/**
 * Modify REST API content for pages to force
 * shortcodes to render since Visual Composer does not
 * do this
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ()
{
   register_rest_field(
          'page',
          'content',
          array(
                 'get_callback'    => 'compasshb_do_shortcodes',
                 'update_callback' => null,
                 'schema'          => null,
          )
       );
});

function compasshb_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request )
{
   WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes(); // This does all the work

   global $post;
   $post = get_post ($object['id']);
   $output['rendered'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );

   return $output;
}
```

Comment: It's working but issue is when we update WordPress then issue occurred, can't we add this or create custom plugin for this?

Comment: Altering core files is the badest thing you could do.

Answer (score 0):

I took it somewhere and update it a bit, to work a bit better :).
in functions.php add this function:

```
/** Function that cuts post excerpt to the number of a word based on previously set global * variable $word_count, which is defined below */

if(!function_exists('kc_excerpt')) {

  function kc_excerpt($excerpt_length = 20) {

    global $word_count, $post;

    $word_count = $excerpt_length;

    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post) != "" ? get_the_excerpt($post) : strip_tags(do_shortcode(get_the_content($post)));

    $clean_excerpt = strpos($post_excerpt, '...') ? strstr($post_excerpt, '...', true) : $post_excerpt;

    /** add by PR */

    $clean_excerpt = strip_shortcodes(remove_vc_from_excerpt($clean_excerpt));
    /** end PR mod */

    $excerpt_word_array = explode (' ',$clean_excerpt);

    $excerpt_word_array = array_slice ($excerpt_word_array, 0, $word_count);

    $excerpt = implode (' ', $excerpt_word_array).'...'; echo ''.$excerpt.'';

  }
}
```

and after that you call it normally `kc_excerpt(20);` and it will return normal post_content/excerpt

Answer (score 0):

How to remove visual composer from wp post: i.e `[vc_row][vc_column width=\"2/3\"][distance][vc_single_image image=\"40530\" img_size=\"large\"][distance][distance][distance][vc_column_text]`
Also WP post remvoe short codes and html tags.

```
while($posts->have_posts()) {
      $postContent = get_the_content();
      //Remove html tags. and short code 
      $postContent = strip_tags( do_shortcode( $postContent ) );
      //Remove visual composer tags [vc_column] etc
      $postContent = preg_replace( "/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/", '', $postContent );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking source code from wordpress api, I did a function to remove some shortcode from content. So this is the result:

```
function removeShortcode($content, $shortcodeList){
  preg_match_all('@\[([^<>&/\[\]\x00-\x20=]++)@', $content, $matches);
  $tagnames = array_intersect($shortcodeList, $matches[1]);
  if(empty($tagnames)){
    return $content;
  }
  $pattern = get_shortcode_regex($tagnames);
  preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $content, $matchesTags);
  foreach ($matchesTags[0] as $key => $value) {
    $content = str_replace($value, $matchesTags[5][$key], $content);
  }
  return $content;
}
```

example:

```
$content = "<p>Hi, this is a [example]<b>example</b>[/example]. [end]</p>";
$shortcodesToRemove = ["example", "end"];
echo removeShortcode($content, $shortcodesToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($posts as $po){
    $services_array[] = array('id'=>$po->ID,'title'=>$po->post_title, 'description'=>do_shortcode($po->post_content));
}
```

- You should try this.